# testing ngrx: dispach action and expect the store

Tags: redux, jasmine, ngrx

Is it possible to dispatch an action inside the test and expect the store , without test effects, reducers, selectors? I really can't find a good example, so I am wondering which is the best practice  to test ngrx.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "store" is a term to represent your entire NgRx system. The reducer is what produces state. I think you want to test how your actions produce state. To do this, you need to focus on your "state creator" which is you reducer

A reducer is a function. Consider this simple example where I activate a "product" I want to test that when an ActivateProduct action appears, that my loading state is set to true

```
export function productActivationReducer(state = initialState, action: ProductActivationActions): ProductActivationState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ProductActivationActionTypes.ActivateProductSuccess:
      return {
        isLoading: true,
        error: null,
        data: action.payload,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Your reducer is a function. The function can be invoked with I would create a test that would invoke the function and test what state is returned.

```
import { productActivationReducer, initialState } from './product-activation.reducer';

  describe('ActivateProductSuccess', () => {
    it('should set the next state', () => {
      action = new ActivateProductSuccess({ foo: 'bar'});
      result = productActivationReducer(initialState, action);
      expect(result.data).toEqual({ foo: 'bar'});
      expect(result.error).toBeNull();
      expect(result.loading).toBe(true);
    });
  });
```